# Segmentation fault (11) on PHP website

Tags: linux, php, segmentation-fault, gdb

I have recently moved a clients WordPress site to a new server. His old server was pretty outdated. It is the only site on the server.

It's been a few weeks and I randomly get these errors in the php log.

```
[notice] child pid 29281 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

I installed gdb and attached the parent process and then did BT when it crashed. I was presented with this output

```
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x00007f0d4208f573 in select () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007f0d42587db5 in apr_sleep () from /usr/lib/libapr-1.so.0
#2  0x00007f0d42e65279 in ap_wait_or_timeout ()
#3  0x00007f0d42e72906 in ap_mpm_run ()
#4  0x00007f0d42e47832 in main ()
```

Unfortunately I have no idea what to do with that or what it means.

Any ideas?

Comment: Update: I just ran aptitude to upgrade the modules and apparently one was broken. It is also updating libc so I'll see if that helps.

Comment: The PID is psuedo-random and can be ignored. Segmentation fault indicates a broken program or library mismatch. The backtrace is of the parent process noticing the death of a child process. If you can capture the backtrace or error logs of the child process that is crashing, you will have more useful information.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this before, and it was due to mismatched `apache` and `apr` packages.  Make sure that all your Apache packages are the same version, and that you're not using (for example) `mod_php5` that's been compiled for a different version.

Comment: After updating all the packages I still get segmentation faults but now the site stays live which is an improvement. I ran apache2ctl -l and here is a list of modules.

  core.c
  mod_log_config.c
  mod_logio.c
  mod_version.c
  prefork.c
  http_core.c
  mod_so.c

Could any of these be the problem?

Comment: Nevermind. Just crashed again.